# How can I find where is the problem with Google map API?

Tags: google-maps

Recently I have fixed google map on my website after Google introduced a new quota policy. And all worked fine. Today I found that map not displaying at all again.

This is how I call google API (I have removed my API key):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY"></script>
```

My maps are here:

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="google-map2"></div>
<div id="map_canvas2" class="google-map2"></div>
<div id="map_canvas3" class="google-map2"></div>
```

Than that's how I call my script in the footer:

```
<script src="google_map.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function(){
  setTimeout(initMap,700);
  });
</script>
```

Script code is here:

```
function initMap()
          {
$(document).foundation();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.461748, -0.361708);
var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.425760, -0.334870);
var latlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.491513, -0.234123);

var myOptions =
{
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var myOptions2 =
{
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var myOptions3 =
{
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), myOptions2);
var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas3"), myOptions3);


var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Head Office"
             });
             var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: latlng2,
    map: map2,
    title:"Head Office 2"
});
var myMarker3 = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: latlng3,
    map: map3,
    title:"Head Office 3"
});
```

}

I haven't done any website changes since my maps were working last time.
Can someone point me to direction how to find where the problem lays?

**EDIT**: I have created JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldqfztev/

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are receiving? if possible, include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added jsfiddle to my question.